# CSS Tooltip's Max-Width Not Taking Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a tooltip component, and I'm trying to make the tooltip's content grow until its max-width is reached, regardless of the width of its parent element. Here's the relevant part of my CSS code:

```
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}

.child {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Despite setting max-width to 400px, the tooltip's content is not expanding as intended and seems to be limited by the width of its parent element (bwre-tooltip).

Despite setting max-width to 400px, the tooltip's content is not expanding as intended and seems to be limited by the width of its parent element (bwre-tooltip).

I've already tried a few solutions, such as changing the width property to auto or max-content, but these adjustments didn't yield the desired result. Additionally, I've checked that there are no conflicting CSS rules affecting the tooltip's width.

Am I missing something? Is there a specific CSS property or technique that I should be using to ensure that the tooltip's content grows until its max-width is reached, regardless of the parent element's width?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to achieving this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Additional Context:

Here's the relevant HTML structure:

```
 <section>
      ipsum ...
      <div class="parent">
        <span class="child">
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliquyam
        </span>
        hello world
      </div>
      ...
    </section>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}

.child {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
    est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    <div class="parent">
      <span class="child">
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliquyam
        </span> hello world
    </div>
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </section>

  <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In addition here is also [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-tdd-odr5yo?file=/index.html)

Comment: Max-width does not cause elements to grow. The only effect of your max-width is that if the width would have been more then 400px without it, the width is limited to 400px.

Comment: When you tried `width: max-content` what was the undesirable result?

Comment: This is due to `position: relative` on the parent, which sets the reference point for the absolute positioned tooltip. You did not specify any values for `left` and `right`, so they both are `auto` - so the width of the tooltip is constrained by the left and right edge of the parent. Now you _could_ specify a larger negative value for both left and right, say -200px, plus `margin: auto` to get it centered between those - but then you might end up in situations where part of the tooltip ends outside of the visible area.

Comment: Or you could remove `relative` from the parent, set both left and right to 0, and replace `bottom` with a margin or translate - but then you won't have the tooltip centered over the triggering element any more. If you really want a solution that covers all eventualities - then you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @Wing I'd been using `white-space: no-wrap` which was preventing `max-content` to take effect. 
That was correct, thanks. 
Can you post your answer so that i can mark as a correct answer?

Comment: @FD3: I see. I'm going to suggest closing as a duplicate because there are ones that exist :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution adding this style to child element:
`margin: 0 -100%;`

But @wing's answer looks like a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have to use box-sizing: border-box; in your tooltip.